# Creating a sub-interpreter in another thread when the GIL is not locked

Tags: cpython

There is an embedded CPython (version 3.11.2) implementation that calls a function without the GIL being held, which in turn spawns a thread and in that thread a function that I can define is invoked. In the following distilled code example this function is called thread_func(). In thread_func() I want to create a sub-interpreter, but I'm struggling to find the correct way to do that. The documentation is a bit confusing for me, because the GIL handling in CPython has changed over time. AFAIK the GIL should not be acquired using [PyGILState_Ensure()](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/init.html#c.PyGILState_Ensure). The documentation says that this function is "not compatible with sub-interpreters". But somehow I have to acquire the GIL so that Py_NewInterpreter() can be called.

I tried to create an auxiliary thread-state attached to the main interpreter state just to acquire the GIL. It seems to work, but I guess that I'm bending the API here. [PyInterpreterState_Main()](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/init.html#c.PyInterpreterState_Main) is documented as "only intended to be used by advanced debugging tools".

```
#include <Python.h>
#include <thread>
// no error handling for brevity

void thread_func()
{
    PyThreadState *auxts = PyThreadState_New(PyInterpreterState_Main());
    PyEval_RestoreThread(auxts); // acquire the GIL

    auto *subts = Py_NewInterpreter();
    PyThreadState_Swap(subts); // switch to the new interpreter

    // work with subts
    // ...

    Py_EndInterpreter(subts); // needs subts to be current
    // GIL is still held and must be released
    PyThreadState_Clear(auxts);
    // didn't use PyThreadState_Delete(auxts) because it doesn't release the GIL
    // instead:
    PyThreadState_Swap(auxts);
    PyThreadState_DeleteCurrent(); // deletes auxts and also releases the GIL
}

void func()
{
    auto thr = std::thread(thread_func);
    thr.join();
}

int main() {
    Py_InitializeEx(0); // implies PyEval_InitThreads()

    Py_BEGIN_ALLOW_THREADS
    func();
    Py_END_ALLOW_THREADS

    Py_FinalizeEx();
    return 0;
}
```

edit: added CPython version

Comment: What's the expected and actual behavior? You forgot to mention *Python* version. https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/init.html#c.Py_NewInterpreter: *Like all other Python/C API functions, **the global interpreter lock must be held** before calling this function ...*.

Comment: The actual behavior is what you read in the example code, because it actually works. But it clearly misuses the CPython API (PyInterpreterState_Main()) and maybe this will fail in some way down the road. At least that's my expectation - in the header file this API is also documented with "Don't use unless you know what you are doing!". I just don't see how else to implement it. I hope an experienced CPython dev can give a clue.